# Erro HTTP 403 - Acesso negado

Tags: asp.net, iis

Tenho um website que utiliza Forms Authentication. Quando testo em debug ou no servidor de desenvolvimento, em IIS7, funciona bem.
Quando publico no servidor de Produção, e pressiono o botão de Logout, ocorre um erro HTTP 403.
O código que tenho para o botão de logout é:

```
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
 FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema substituindo

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

por

```
Response.Redirect("./mypage.aspx")
```

Pelo menos, no meu caso funcionou como desejado.